# Delete all lines where column 1 has specific numeric entries

Tags: unix, awk

I'm new to Unix and I have a large csv file where I want to delete all the lines where Column 1 has values greater than 1.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to delete lines where `col 1 >1`, it means that you want to keep those whose `col 1 <=1`. Hence, this `awk` will make it:

```
awk '$1<=1' file > new_file
```

If you want to set it the other way round, negate the condition:

```
awk '!($1>1)' file > new_file
```

As per Jaypal's good suggestion, you may have the case in which you need to indicate the field separator. If so, do it with the `-F` parameter:

```
awk -F"," '$1<=1' file > new_file   # field separator is ,
awk -F";" '$1<=1' file > new_file   # field separator is ;
```

Comment: Good one, though since it is a csv file it would be a good idea to set the delimiter to `,`. Having said that, I have seen many questions being posted as CSV with `tabs` or something completely different that a conventional `,` as delimiter. Would be good to mention about it none the less. `:)`

Comment: Nice suggestion, @jaypal :) updated to reflect that. Thanks man!

Comment: amigo en necesidad es un amigo de hecho!! `;)`

Comment: Eres un crack!! ;) Olé y olé